# Disabling a checkbox in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to disable a check box which is in table data

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>       
    <th id="spanDate"></th>
    <th id="spanDate1"></th>        
    <th id="spanDate2"></th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>00:00-03:00</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c" name="time" value="00:00-03:00">
        <button onclick="fun()"><-></button>
        <script>
            function fun()
            {
                 document.getElementById("c").disabled=true;
            }
        </script>
   </td>
</tr>
```

but when I click the button the page refreshes but the check box is still enabled.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @JamesAMohler — It doesn't really matter. That's the expected and standard behaviour.

Comment: "the page refreshes" - the refresh code is not in your sample, so we can only speculate that/how you are reloading the page.  If you reload the page, all existing html/controls are reset to the state set by the page load.  Here's a jsfiddle with your code as provided, showing it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/u9yyjgLx/

Comment: @freedomn-m — There's a submit button. That's causing the page to refresh. The form is implicit.

Comment: @freedomn-m — The default type of a button element is submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You click the submit button
2. The checkbox is disabled
3. The form submits
4. The browser loads a new page
5. The checkbox isn't disabled in the new page (since it is a new checkbox)

If you want to keep it disabled then you'll need to have the server deliver a page that has it disabled by default (or not submit the form so the browser stays on the page with the original checkbox that you disabled with JS).

Comment: But basically what I am doing is I want to make a toggle button which enables/disables the checkbox and as soon as I submit the whole table it updates the database on the basis of the checkboxes.But I want it to retain its originality even after submitting ie if a checkbox was disabled I want it to be disabled  even after submitting.How can I achieve this?

Comment: "you'll need to have the server deliver a page that has it disabled by default" — the sensible way to do that is have a server side programming language set the `disabled` attribute. The specifics of that depend on the language you are using on the server.

Comment: I don't want it to pick any default value instead I want it to pick the current value for that particular checkbox

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter — That's the value you need to set as default for the page as it is loaded that time.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way.

```
function fun(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //stop refresh page when clicked
  document.getElementById('c').setAttribute("disabled","true");
}
```

Comment: if e.preventDefault() does not work, you can try  <button onclick="fun(); return false;"><-></button>